# Why my preview and my final photo are cropped?

Tags: android, camera

I explain to you my problem.
I made a personal camera in android.
It has a preview layout and a button to make a photo. The app uses only front camera if the phone doesn't have a rear camera...
Now my problem is this, the preview and the output file seem to display a cutted portion of what camera really see. To explain you better, if i use my stock camera ( that pre-installed on the phone, with 0 zoom and from the same distance ) i can see all my face and chest, with my camera i can only see my face so the preview and final photo are cutted in a certain why i can't get.
Someone can help me?

Here is where i set the camera parameters

public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

```
private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";
private Context mContext;
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);

    mCamera = camera;
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    //get the holder and set this class as the callback, so we can get camera data here
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    for(Camera.Size str: mSupportedPreviewSizes)
        Log.e(TAG, str.width + "/" + str.height);

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try {
        //when the surface is created, we can set the camera to draw images in this surfaceholder@Override

        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceCreated " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int w, int h) {
    Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged => w=" + w + ", h=" + h);
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here
    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

    if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
        mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
    }

    float ratio;
    if(mPreviewSize.height >= mPreviewSize.width)
        ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.height / (float) mPreviewSize.width;
    else
        ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.width / (float) mPreviewSize.height;
    setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) (width * ratio));
}

private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

    if (sizes == null)
        return null;

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
            continue;

        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }

    return optimalSize;
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    //our app has only one screen, so we'll destroy the camera in the surface
    //if you are unsing with more screens, please move this code your activity
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
}
```

Comment: Show me your code...

Comment: Which one?
Main activity or camera view?

Comment: All the related code, you can use gist for that.

Comment: I edited the question, i think that some errors are in there

Comment: Which resolution do you choose for preview and capture? On many devices the field of view depends on the picture aspect ratio. For this reason, always choose same aspect ratio for preview and capture.

Comment: In the main activity i just defined the view of the camera to be squared, but it envolve only view, not camera or preview...
And i dunno which resolution i choose ( i think the native one ) because i found the code in a tutorial